# Can't find an element while scraping the TradingView website

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, tradingview-api

I've been trying to scrape stock prices from TradingView. I am using Python, and the requests and BeautifulSoup modules.

So, I used this code:

```py
response = requests.get('https://fr.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
price_element = soup.find('span', class_='last-JWoJqCpY js-symbol-last')
print(price_element)
```

When I print `price_element`, it returns only the `span` tag itself but not what it contains.

Let me know if I made a mistake or if it's TradingView that is hiding these elements.

Comment: surely the API is better.

Comment: I guess its because your tool is not executing the page JavaScript. If you load the page with JS disabled, it’s mostly empty (the price at least). Also the class you’re using for the selector is generated and your script will stop working any time they make a change.

Comment: oh thanks y'all i noticed that i should've used selenium instead of BeautifulSoup to scrape trading view because of the JS.